Catch a compiler exception in macroexpand
I have an assertion that checks key correctness at compile time:
(defn assert-keys [check-map valid-keys]
  (let [k (set (keys check-map))]
    (when-not (set/subset? k valid-keys)
      (throw (ex-info "Function call contains invalid key." {:submitted-keys k
                                                             :valid-keys     valid-keys})))))

It is invoked in a macro:
(defmacro with-hooks [{:keys [read write] :as options} & body]
  (assert-keys options #{:read :write})
  `(binding [*read-hook*  (or ~read  *read-hook*)
             *write-hook* (or ~write *write-hook*)]
     ~@body))

In this case it will check that the options map may contain the keys :read and :write, and nothing more.
The thing is, I'd like to write a test for this. The code will cause a compiler error on macro expand if there's an invalid key. Is there any way of catching this error in a test?

This is the solution I found. Create a macro for testing:
(defmacro catch-assert [body]
  (try
    (eval body)
    0
    (catch clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException e
      (if (re-find #"Function call contains invalid key"
                   (str e))
        1
        -1))
    (catch Exception _e
      -1)))

It returns:
0, call didn't produce exception.
1, compiler exception being tested for.
-1, other exceptions.
Then I call in my test:
(deftest valid-keys
  (testing "Valid hook keys"
    (is (= 0 (catch-assert
              (with-hooks {:read ()
                           :write ()})))))
  (testing "Invalid hook key"
    (is (= 1 (catch-assert
              (with-hooks {:rea ()}))))))


You can use macroexpand. Note that the macro would have to be the topmost form since macroexpand doesn't go beyond the top form.
As an alternative, a common approach is to have a regular defn that does what the macro does, and then defmacro would simply call that function.

Another option is to use the ability to load code from a string:
(ns so
  (:require
   [clojure.set :as set])
  (:use
   [clojure.test]))

(defn assert-keys [check-map valid-keys]
  (let [k (set (keys check-map))]
    (when-not (set/subset? k valid-keys)
      (throw (ex-info "Function call contains invalid key."
                      {:submitted-keys k
                       :valid-keys     valid-keys})))))

(def ^:dynamic *read-hook*)
(def ^:dynamic *write-hook*)

(defmacro with-hooks [{:keys [read write] :as options} & body]
  (assert-keys options #{:read :write})
  `(binding [*read-hook*  (or ~read  *read-hook*)
             *write-hook* (or ~write *write-hook*)]
     ~@body))

(defn run-load
  [s]
  (try (load-string s) (catch Throwable t t)))

(deftest compile-time-issues
  (let [p (run-load "(with-hooks {:read 42} *read-hook*)")
        f (run-load "(with-hooks {:ready 42} *read-hook*)")]
    (is (= p 42))
    (is (instance? Throwable f))))


